# Jenkins scripted or declarative pipeline - how to set job description text

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know how to set the description text for a job defined in scripted or declarative pipeline in Jenkins ?
Reason: I want to add some meaningful text (small documentation) about the job.

Answer (score 6):

This solution changes the description of a **job item via a groovy script in jenkins**. I only used it in a freestyle job, but i think it should be also working in an *scripted pipeline*:

```
import jenkins.model.*
final jenkins   = Jenkins.getInstanceOrNull()
final myJob     = jenkins.getItem("MyJobName")

description = "<h1 style=\"color:green\">The newest build has number ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</h1>"
myJob.setDescription(description)
myJob.save()
```

This solution changes the **description of a build**:
Use 'currentbuild' global variable.

I.e. declarative pipeline:

```
script { currentbuild.description = 'New Description' }
```

Works the same in scripted pipelines :)

Reference: https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals

Comment: This adds description to specific build but not job itself.

Comment: Ok, i added 'This solution changes the description of a job item via a groovy script in jenkins.', i hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

for declarative pipeline

```
script {
       currentBuild.description = "description env var if required :${env.ver}"
}
```

for scripted

```
currentBuild.description = "description env var if required :${env.ver}"
```

Comment: Again, this adds description to specific build but not job itself.

Comment: So you want that every build will change the job description ?

Comment: Not every build description - job description.

Comment: you can change the job description when you create it using the DSL , do you want to change the job description every build ?